# How to set an objects location and rotation to individual particles in a system

Tags: python, rendering, modifiers, particles

I have a particle system representing a school of fish, my goal is to render a cryptomatte of each fish in view of the camera individually so I can generate a masked dataset from it (index/semantic labeling doesn't work with particle systems). This has led me down a rabbit hole of blender particle system api docs and currently, my solution is this: do not render the particle system, spawn an identical fish at the location/rotation of each particle, then render in between positions. When testing this, however, the spawned fish "testFish" does not move to the proper locations or rotations within frame in the output renders.

```
import bpy
import mathutils
import os

ob = bpy.context.active_object
dg = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
ob = bpy.context.object.evaluated_get(dg)

# should print out all particles in selected system
#print(ob.particle_systems[0].particles[0].is_visible)

bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'
bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = "insertdatadirectoryhere"

#Output open exr .exr files
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'JPEG'
bpy.context.scene.cycles.samples = 1


# Switch on nodes and get reference
bpy.context.scene.use_nodes = True
tree = bpy.context.scene.node_tree
links = tree.links

## Clear default nodes
for node in tree.nodes:
    tree.nodes.remove(node)

# Create a node for outputting the rendered image
image_output_node = tree.nodes.new(type="CompositorNodeOutputFile")
image_output_node.label = "Image_Output"
image_output_node.base_path = "insertdatadirectoryhere"
image_output_node.location = 400,0

# Create a node for outputting the index of each object
mask_output_node = tree.nodes.new(type="CompositorNodeOutputFile")
mask_output_node.label = "Mask_Output"
mask_output_node.base_path = "insertdatadirectoryhere"
mask_output_node.location = 400,-200

# Create a node for the output from the renderer
render_layers_node = tree.nodes.new(type="CompositorNodeRLayers")
render_layers_node.location = 0,0

# Link all the nodes together
links.new(render_layers_node.outputs['Image'], image_output_node.inputs['Image'])
links.new(render_layers_node.outputs['CryptoObject00'], mask_output_node.inputs['Image'])


#we have the information we need to mask out individual fish
particle_system = bpy.context.object.particle_systems[0]
particles = particle_system.particles
masknum = 0
fish = bpy.data.objects.new("testFish", bpy.data.collections[1].objects[0].data)
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(fish)
fish.scale = (0.1,0.1,0.1)
print(dir(fish))
for particle in particles:
    image_output_node.base_path = "insertdatadirectoryhere"
    mask_output_node.base_path = "insertdatadirectoryhere"+str(masknum)
    masknum+=1
    fish.location = particle.location
    bpy.context.scene.cursor.location = particle.location
    #fish_euler = euler_from_quaternion(particle.rotation.x,particle.rotation.y,particle.rotation.z,particle.rotation.w)
    fish.rotation_euler = particle.rotation.to_euler('XYZ')
    bpy.context.scene.cursor.location = (0,0,0)
    print(fish.location, fish.rotation_euler)
    # Render the particle
    bpy.ops.render.render(write_still = True)
    
fish.location = (9999,9999,9999)
bpy.ops.render.render(write_still = True)
objs = [bpy.context.scene.objects['testFish']]
bpy.ops.object.delete({"selected_objects": objs})
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, after looking through the docs there was literally a `to_euler()` function in the Quaternion class. Here's what worked for me:

```
fish.rotation_euler = particle.rotation.to_euler('XYZ')
fish.rotation_euler[2] += math.pi/2
```